# How to stop a previous viewController's activity after being popped

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a navigation controller that segues, using push, to a second view controller. I use:

```
controller.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

And this works. This code causes my controller to be popped off the stack and it returns to the root view. However, I can still hear my code running (e.g. music/sound effects) in the root view.

I have explored a few avenues.

**One** is to create a function that runs when my back buttons is pressed. Currently, it removes all the actions/pauses all the music:

```
func pauseAndRemoveEverything() {
    for child in fgNode.children { child.removeAllActions() }
    for child in bgNode.children { child.removeAllActions() }
    soundEffectsPlayer?.volume = 0
    musicPlayer?.volume = 0
    soundEffectsPlayer?.stop()
    musicPlayer?.stop()
}
```

The **second** option is to use multi-threading and dispatching little blocks of code; then cancelling them all when the user hits the back button. Currently my code is all on timed blocks, and I don't know how the dispatch will affect this, or whether it is more trouble than it is worth.

I want the actions on the previous controller to completely cease on segue, and reduce the effect it has on memory and energy use when this occurs. How do I do this?

Comment: hi, popToRootViewController() returns an array of ViewController.
you can stop all here

you can also use the 
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) entry in your viewcontroller to stop your stuff

Comment: @divol That's my question -- how?

Comment: override the viewWillDisappear of the popped view controller, it's called each time the view go away as for un pop. It's the place to stop your async stuff